# In CUDA, why cudaMemcpy2D and cudaMallocPitch consume a lot of time

Tags: performance, cuda, gpu, nvidia, memory-bandwidth

As mentioned in title, I found that the function of `cudaMallocPitch()` consumes a lot of time and `cudaMemcpy2D()` consumes quite some time as well.

Here is the code I am using:

```
cudaMallocPitch((void **)(&SrcDst), &DeviceStride, Size.width * sizeof(float), Size.height);

cudaMemcpy2D(SrcDst, DeviceStride * sizeof(float), 
        ImgF1, StrideF * sizeof(float), 
        Size.width * sizeof(float), Size.height,
        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

In implementation, the `Size.width` and `Size.height` are both 4800. The time consuming for `cudaMallocPitch()` is about 150-160ms (multiple tests in case accidents) and `cudaMemcpy2D()` consumes about 50ms.

It seems not possible that the memory bandwidth between the CPU and GPU is so limited, but I cannot see any errors in code, so what is the reason?

By the way, the hardware I am using are Intel I7-4770K CPU and Nvidia Geforce GTX 780(quite good hardware without error).

Comment: Have you tried the bandwidthTest for your architecture for getting a reference? A `4800x4800` `float` array taking `50ms` to be transferred means a bandwidth of about `2GB/s`. I'm not sure if you have to count also the allocated pitch in the matrix size, in which case the speed increases. With pinned memory, my laptop equipped with a GT540M card touches `6GB/s`.

Answer (score 3):

There are many factors here which may be impacting performance.

Regarding `cudaMallocPitch`, if it happens to be the first cuda call in your program, it will incur additional overhead.

Regarding `cudaMemcpy2D`, this is accomplished under the hood via a sequence of individual memcpy operations, one per row of your 2D area (i.e. 4800 individual DMA operations).  This will necessarily incur additional overhead compared to an ordinary `cudaMemcpy` operation (which transfers the entire data area in a single DMA transfer).  Furthermore, peak transfer speeds are only achieved when the host side memory buffer is pinned.  Finally, you don't indicate anything about your platform.  If you are on windows, then WDDM will interfere with full transfer performance for this operation, and we don't know what kind of PCIE link you are on.

4800*4800*4/0.050 = 1.84GB/s which is a significant fraction of the ~3GB/s that is roughly available for a non-pinned transfer across PCIE 2.0.  The reduction from 3GB to 1.84GB is easily explainable by the other factors I list above.

If you want full transfer performance, use pinned memory and don't use a pitched/2D transfer.

Comment: This question is asking primarily about host<->device transfer characteristics.  Whether or not a pitched allocation will be used for texturing has no bearing on the transfer characteristics between host<->device, for that pitched allocation.

Comment: Texturing, in various circumstances, can be done from 1. A linear memory allocation  2. A pitched memory allocation  3. A `cudaArray`.   I assume your question pertains to `cudaArray`.  This question does not.

Comment: If you're asking about `cudaArray`, I'm not aware of detailed documentation discussing any of the things you may be asking about (host->device transfer characteristics, underlying storage patterns, etc.).  You're welcome to post any question you wish, of course.